# Predict function in R for GLM

Tags: r, predict

I am using the following data:

```
Dose    Cells   Dicentrics  
0.1     328     2   
0.2     723     1   
0.5     513     4   
1.0     369     4   
1.5     280     7   
2.0     361     19  
3.0     238     26
```

I am using `read.table` and `attach` to load the table. I was suggested to use the model Dicentrics=Cells(b1+b2 Dose + b3 Dose^2). Hence I fit a glm

```
fit1 <- glm(Dicentrics ~ Cells+Cells*Dose+Cells*(Dose^2)-1, family=poisson(link="identity"))
```

Now I'd like to visualise it and plot it on top of the Dicentric/Cells ~ Dose Plot. [image]

I would like to plot my line of prediction on this plot.

When I use `predict(fit1)` I get

```
 predict(fit1, type="response") # predicted values

        1         2         3         4         5 
 1.124833  2.521284  2.677220  4.906738  7.802772 
        6         7 
17.662902 26.304251
```

Comment: I don't think your model is what you expect it to be. You probably mean `I(Dose^2)`. I also am suspicious that this is a good model, but lack the necessary background information to be certain.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi dicentrics can only be discrete, hence I used Poisson, and since the model is quadratic, I used the identity link

Comment: @Roland I don't know why it's a bad model? I got 0.001047  ,  9.871158 and -0.008227 to be estimates for b1, b2 and b3 using summary(fit1) , and I should be able to plot the quadratic, which I am unable to do

Comment: From your question regarding the plot it appears you actually want to model `Dicentric/Cells`. I suspect that this is a proportion and you should model this with the appropriate kind of GLM (not a Poisson model). Also, you did not specify a quadratic model.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I think because the next step is to compare the model with the log model. Do you suggest using gaussian on Dicentrics/Cells ~ Dose + Dose^2?

Comment: @Roland the model is E(Disentrics)=Cells(b1+b2 Dose + b3 Dose^2), for the quadratic model. This is a bilogical experiment where disentric is some type of cells and cells is the total number

Comment: Yes, but you did not specify this to R. Read `help("formula")`.

Comment: And you need to decide what you want to do: Model disentrics in dependence of number of cells and dose or model the proportion of disentrics in cells in dependence of dose. Usually you would be interested in the latter.

Comment: @Roland Yes, I'm interested in the proportion, so I'm gonna try to do it with a gaussian and report back, something along (Dicentrics/Cells ~ Dose + Dose^2)

Comment: No, a gaussian model is not appropriate for proportions. Maybe you could use betaregression, but we are now clearly off-topic for this site.